# Ввод-вывод данных из структуры

Tags: ассемблер

Не могу понять как правильно реализовать ввод и вывод данных в структуру.

Мой код:

```
ASSUME CS: CODE_SEG, DS: DATA_SEG


STUDENT STRUC
NUMBER DB 3,2 DUP('1')
NAME_S DB 19 DUP('2')
SPEC DB 6 DUP('3')
AGE DB 6 DUP('4')
CR_LF DB 0DH,0AH
STUDENT ENDS

DATA_SEG SEGMENT
STUDENTS STUDENT <>
ENDSTR DB '$'
DATA_SEG ENDS

CODE_SEG SEGMENT
start:

MOV AX,DATA_SEG
MOV DS,AX


LEA DI,STUDENTS

MOV AH,0AH
LEA DX,STUDENTS.NUMBER
INT 21H


MOV AH,09H
LEA DX,[di]
INT 21H

;EXIT--------—
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H

CODE_SEG ENDS
end start
```

Comment: Что значит "ввод" и "вывод"? Нужно ввести поля структуры с консоли и вывести их туда же?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала изучите как на самом деле [работает функция 0Ah](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/dos_0018.php). Введите с её помощью все члены структуры, предварительно правильно их описав (то есть первым байтом указать максимальную длину поля, и не забыть, что во второй байт поля будет записана реальная длина ввода).

А для вывода используйте [функцию 40h](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/dos_0067.php). В качестве буфера давайте ей адрес поля+2, в качестве длины - второй байт поля. И после вывода каждого поля выводите CR/LF, уже неважно каким способом.

Вот как-то так примерно (тут немножно "грязных хаков" с вызовами, но это уже по привычке):

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h

start:
    mov dx, offset student.s_name
    call input    
    mov dx, offset student.s_spec
    call input

    mov cl, [student.s_name+1]
    lea dx, student.s_name+2
    call print
    mov cl, [student.s_spec+1]
    lea dx, student.s_spec+2

print:
    xor ch, ch
    mov bx, 1
    mov ah, 40h
    int 21h

crlf:
    mov dx, offset cr_lf
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h    
    ret

input:    
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h
    jmp short crlf

students struc
  s_name db 10, 0, 20 dup(?)
  s_spec db 10, 0, 20 dup(?)
students ends

student students <>

cr_lf db 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'

end start
end
```